# Repeat last change multiple times without replacing original count

Tags: vim

The documentation for `.` says:

> Repeat last change, with count replaced with [count].

Is it possible to repeat one change without replacing count and without resorting to macros?

Alternately, is it possible to repeat a change multiple times without the number being interpreted as the count value to the command?

Context:

I was working on [this](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/4d1aaf2fb11838287d000036) VimGolf challenge where the objective is to reverse the alphabet:

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` becomes `zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`

My approach was to jump to z and use `"Ax` to append each letter to then of register `a`, and then paste register a, which would contain the reversed string. To repeat `"Ax`, recording a macro and using `25@q` works, pressing `.` 26 times works, but `26.` and `26"Ax` do not work because 26 is applied to the count of `x`, which makes the command attempt to delete 26 characters to the right of the cursor.

Comment: Arg... I can only get to 13 characters! Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need here is macro, not `[count].` because `.` repeat the last cmd. and if you give it count, as you have seen, the count would be applied on the last cmd, so it would be `26x`, not `pressing x 26 times`. usually there is no difference, but if your cursor is at the end of the line, `26x` does the same as `x`.

What you need is a macro, if you don't want to `qx...q`, there are some tricks you may want to know: (without thinking about the count of keystrokes too much)

### trick1

use the `=` register:

```
26@='"Ax'<cr>
```

this does what you want.

### trick2

use the `.` register.

Assume at the start point, your cursor is on the line1 col1 so, press: `A"Ax<esc>U26@.`

the first `A` jump to EOL and entering INSERT, big `U` undo the inserted text of current line, and **save into '.' (dot) register**.

Now you can "replay" the reg 26 times.

regarding this challenge, the most straightforward solution (might not be the shortest) would be: `set revins` option, in short: `se ri`.

hope it helps.